# Where can I find a complete documentation for Hyperledger fabric Client (HFC)?

Tags: ibm-cloud, hyperledger

I'm trying to create a Hyperledger App using HFC that will connect to a blockchain set-up in Bluemix.

However, I can't find a comprehensive documentation related to register and enrollment.

I saw a sample code for enrolling (chain.enroll) and for registering and enrolling (chain.registerAndEnroll).  However, I cannot find a sample for register only (e.g., chain.register).  I hope to have a register only so that the admin will do the registration of UserA, and UserA will be the one who will enroll so that the necessary key files will be stored in the computer of UserA and not in the computer of the admin.

In addition, I can't find a sample code that will allow the registration that includes attributes.  The registration example I saw involves only the enrollmentID and affiliation.

Answer (score 1):

Foloow the official documentation of hyperledger/fabric.

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

For an app you should refer to documentations of Node SDK of hyperledger/fabric